# Running a windows service as domain user when connectivity to Active Directory is not there?

Tags: uwp, active-directory, windows-services, windows-installer

We have a Windows service running in client machines as an agent which downloads the MSI from the server and install it. One of the MSI is responsible of installing an UWP app to a domain user account, because of this reason the service has to be running as a domain user.

Everything works fine when clients have VPN connectivity, but when VPN is not connected service can't start as it can't verify the user.

Is there any other service account we can use for windows service which do install the UWP app but should not depend on active directory server.

Tried running the service local service account & network service account, app is not available to correct user.